# How to get email alerts when a cell value changes (based on Formula) on Google sheets?

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want a notification/email when a cell value in column 5 of the spreasheet changes to 'Buy' which is based on formula =IF(AND(B2>D2),"Buy","Skip"). Attachment Link provided below. The Sheet autorefreshes based on Googlefinance data.

I have tried the below script, but it triggers notification/Email only when I change the cell manually. I am not a code writer, but have managed to find below script and added some tweaks of my own.
Can somebody please help me in resolving this or provide an alternate solution?
Also script written on third Party apps will be appreciated.

```
function triggerOnEdit(e)

{
  showMessageOnUpdate(e);
}

function showMessageOnUpdate(e)
{
  var range = e.range;
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("range updated " +   range.getA1Notation());  
}

function checkStatusIsBuy(e)
{
  var range = e.range;
  
  if(range.getColumn() <= 5 && 
     range.getLastColumn() >=5 )
  {
    var edited_row = range.getRow();
    
    var strongBuy = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(edited_row,5).getValue();
    if(strongBuy == 'Buy')
    {
      return edited_row;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
function triggerOnEdit(e)
{
  showMessageOnBuy(e);
}
function showMessageOnBuy(e)
{
  var edited_row = checkStatusIsBuy(e);
  if(edited_row > 0)
  {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Row # "+edited_row+"Buy!");
  }
}

function sendEmailOnBuy(e)
{
  var buy_row = checkStatusIsBuy(e);
  
  if(buy_row <= 0)
  {
    return;
  }
  
  sendEmailByRow(buy_row);
}

function sendEmailByRow(row)
{
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,1,row,5).getValues();
  var row_values = values[0];
  
  var mail = composeBuyEmail(row_values);
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(" subject is "+mail.subject+"\n message "+mail.message);
}

function composeBuyEmail(row_values)
{
  var stock_name = row_values[0];
  
  var cmp = row_values[1];
  
  var volume = row_values[2];

  var message = "The Status has changed: "+stock_name+" "+cmp+
    " Volume "+volume;
  var subject = "Strong Buy "+stock_name+" "+cmp
  
  return({message:message,subject:subject});
}

function triggerOnEdit(e)
{
  sendEmailOnBuy(e);
}

var admin_email='sendemail@gmail.com';

function sendEmailByRow(row)
{
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,1,row,5).getValues();
  var row_values = values[0];
  
  var mail = composeBuyEmail(row_values);
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(" subject is "+mail.subject+"\n message "+mail.message);
```

[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12k5DF8rvuKex77B8uRWpx1FoMmSNaMdGvhNEEbXKCFc/edit?usp=sharing][1]

Comment: I have just asked you an access to your speardsheet.

Comment: Granted access! 

Comment: Same problem as this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48173483/create-google-sheets-email-trigger-based-on-stock-price. In fact, I don't know how we can detect automatically the result of the function. OnEdit needs a manual entry.

Comment: No problem bro, thanks for trying! Hopefully someone has a solution for this.

Comment: It is unclear how the values in cells `B2` and `D2` get updated. If they are updated manually, use an `on edit` [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable). If the values in these cells are fetched through `googlefinance()`, you may be able to use an `on change` trigger to run your code. If no event is sent with an `on change` trigger, you will have to use a [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers).

Comment: The value in B2 changes which is the current market price of the stock, as per google finance it gets updated after every 15 mins. The code itself is based on on edit trigger. However, the value in D2 is set by me, i.e if a stock crosses a particular price, it tells me to buy based on Formula which is mentioned in Column E2.

Answer (score 1):

Apps script triggers cannot be trigerred by non manual input as specified in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions):

> Script executions and API requests do not cause triggers to run. For example, calling Range.setValue() to edit a cell does not cause the spreadsheet's onEdit trigger to run.

What you can do instead is to set up a time-based trigger that scans your column 5 at regular interval and sends you an email if a cell contains 'Buy':

```
function sendEmailOnUpdate() {
      var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('E2:E').getValues();
      
      for (i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
        var cell = range[i];
    
        if (cell == 'Buy') {
          // Send email using Gmail
        }
      }
    }
```

To set the trigger, head to Triggers and select time-based:

[image]

If you don't want to receive more emails for a cell you receive an alert for, make sure to make apps script change its value once the email has been sent.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I’ll try this method. Just one question, how do I make the app script change its value, once the email has been sent?

Comment: You can use the method .setValue() inside your if: `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getRange(i + 2, 5).setValue('Sent')`